# Flagging in mobile view

Tags: bug, mobile-web

When flagging a question on mobile view, the pop-up becomes unusable. After choosing the first option and the content changes you can't see the rest of the options or submit.

Happens when there are no answers/few comments and the answer textarea is visible. The pop-up is forced behind the textarea.